# On Tensor calculus and Relativity

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, reference-request, tensors, general-relativity

I'm from mathematical background, I want to LEARN tensor as well as relativity(mathematical approach), which book is helpful for me?and what do I need to know first to better understand those topics? Your help will be highly appreciable...

Comment: You'll probably get a better response from the [phyics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: study change of basis and change of components in vectorspaces and its tensors